# views_embed_view and template

Tags: 7, views

In my views-view--etc.tpl.php file I have

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
<?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which I have amended to

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
<div class="view-title">
<h2>My View Title</h2>
</div>
```

I want to use

```
<?php print views_embed_view('viewname', 'displayname', $node->field_fieldname['und']['0']['tid']); ?>
```

to embed the view but if the view returns zero results I still end up with and empty div and h2 title. Using module_invoke completely hides this, as does encapsulating the tpl file in  "if ($rows):", neither of which I want to do.

Can someone please tell me what the function is to use to completely hide the view div classes and title in the tpl file if no results?

Comment: Just to clarify, why can't you use `if ($rows):`? Does it produce an error?

Comment: No, it doesn't produce any error but I have been told to do it via function rather than via template.

Comment: I have same problem views_embed_view() ignores template file.